# efficiency and inefficiency of recursion methods in java

Tags: java, recursion

I have a question on recursion , what are the efficiencies and inefficiencies of recursion , I know it will use more memory but is it good to use it and when to use it?

Comment: Have you done some research on the question? What have you found?

Comment: While subject is interesting, your question is not very good because it is very broad, and probably to answer it properly we could write a book. Try to be more specific about things you want to know. Also it could be helpful if you explain what you think about these points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the size of the objects you are recursing.

If you are doing recursion over objects that are already in memory, memory impact will be neglible because it's simply using the same objects that are already in memory over and over. Just see which objects/variables you can re-use to keep memory footprint low.

If you are recursing over directories/files etc.. and constantly loading stuff from disc or database that is not in memory yet, it can become very expensive to do so because of the loading, allocating and then processing.

It all depends on what you really are doing... and you haven't provided much detail.